# moving through Java ArrayList with a undo button

Tags: java, arraylist, undo

I know that I am missing something simple here. I have got this homework all done except for moving through my ArrayList.  This is a undo feature of a calculator that I need to pull and remove a object from an ArrayList. Here is the method:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
     {
         Status state;
         state = new Status(operand1, operator, operand2, displayBox.getText());
         //ArrayList that I am coping into 
         listOfStates.add(state);
         super.actionPerformed(e);


         if(e.getSource() == undo )
         {
             Status previousState  = (Status) listOfStates.get(listOfStates.size()- 1); 
             displayBox.setText(" ");
              displayBox.setText(displayBox.getText()  +  previousState.op1); 
//This is where I need help at?  This calls a method of Status that only returns op1 IE 
//first operator

          }   
      }
```

The whole Class is here

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
/**
 *
 * 
 * 
 */
public class BetterCalculator extends Calculator 

{   
    //attributes
    protected JButton undo; 
    protected ArrayList<Status> listOfStates; 
    private int numClicks = 0;





    public BetterCalculator()
    {
        super();
        listOfStates = new ArrayList<Status>();

    }


    public void createUserInterface3()
    {
        createUserInterface2();
        undo = new JButton("undo");
        jPanel.add(undo);
        undo.setBackground(Color.red);
       undo.setToolTipText("This is the undo feature");
       undo.addActionListener(this);

    }


     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
     {
         Status state;
         state = new Status(operand1, operator, operand2, displayBox.getText());
         //ArrayList that I am coping into 
         listOfStates.add(state);
         super.actionPerformed(e);


         if(e.getSource() == undo )
         {
             Status previousState  = (Status) listOfStates.get(listOfStates.size()- 1); 
             displayBox.setText(" ");
              displayBox.setText(displayBox.getText()  +  previousState.op1);

          }   
      }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        BetterCalculator myCalc;
        myCalc = new BetterCalculator();
        myCalc.createUserInterface3();



    }
}
```

Status Class

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
/**
 * Write a description of class Status here.
 * 
 * 
 *  This is a class to get the status for the undo feature
 */
public class Status 
{   
    //attributes
   protected double op1;
   protected char opt;
   protected double op2;
   protected String soFar;
    //constructors



    public Status(double o1, char op, double o2, String sf)
    {
        op1 = o1;
        opt = op;
        op2 = o2;
        soFar = sf;
    }



  //Methods
   public double getOp1()
    {
        return op1;
    }


     public char getOpt()
    {
        return opt;
    }


    public double getOp2()
    {
        return op2;
    }






}
```

Thanks for any help. I know I am missing it on how to pull the object out of the ArrayList and then remove it.

Comment: First of all the "whole" class doesn't compile

Comment: I guess I put too much code in sorry. "whole class is the whole class that has the method that I am having issues with. The action actionPerformed method, mainly the if statement. Whole class is not the class name. The class name is BetterCalculator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is capability to take object out of a collection and remove it, you might want to consider to use [Queue](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) or [Deque](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) instead, depend on your need from which end you want to remove the object.